# Restricting access to Service account within a namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I have a external service name type service created for RDS in Namespace1.
I dont want pods or any resource in namespace2 to access the rds service in namespace2.
I tried with below code but still I am able to access.
Any idea why its not working?

```
   ---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: mysqlsa
  namespace: namespace2
automountServiceAccountToken: false
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql-client
  namespace: namespace2
spec:
  serviceAccountName: mysqlsa
  containers:
  - image: mysql:8
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: busybox
  restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: namespace2
  name: mysqlaccess
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list","create","update","patch","delete"] 
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: mysqlaccess-binding
  namespace: namespace2
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: mysqlaccess 
subjects: 
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: mysqlsa 
  namespace: namespace2
```

I am able to connect to rds service in namespace1

```
 kubectl exec -it mysql-client  -n namespace2 -- bash                       
    bash-4.4# mysql -h my-database-svc.namespace1.svc.cluster.local -P 3306 -u admin -ppassword
    mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
    Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
    Your MySQL connection id is 900
    Server version: 8.0.32 Source distribution
    
    Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
    
    Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
    affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
    owners.
    
    Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
    
    mysql> exit
```

Auth shows no

```
kubectl auth can-i list services --as=system:serviceaccount:namespace2:mysqlsa -n namespace1
    no
```

Comment: you mean: ` any resource in namespace2 to access the rds service in namespace1`, right?

Comment: any resource in namespace2 should not access the rds service in namespace1. Looks like external service name does not work as we expect for normal service. Looks like it does the dns lookup unlike normal service

Comment: Roles are only to configure apiserver access, not traffic between pods. You need a NetworkPolicy for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DNS lookup doesn't use the Kubernetes API and doesn't take any credentials.  Kubernetes RBAC rules don't apply here.

I don't believe there's any way to prevent a Service name from resolving in selected Pods.  (A comment suggested network policies; those only apply at the IP/CIDR-block level.)

In this example, hiding the ExternalName Service wouldn't really do anything.  That Service just provides a DNS alias inside the cluster; if the caller knew the AWS host name of the RDS instance, it could directly connect to the RDS instance anyways.  A caller would also need to know the credentials to access the database.  I wouldn't especially worry about this case.

Comment: Thankyou..You are correct. I understood now.
I am trying to achieve this scenario using security group for pods.

Comment: I might focus on the database credentials as the main way to secure the database.  As far as external services like RDS are concerned, they can't tell where in the cluster a request came from, and it's very possible containers in the "right" and "wrong" namespace are running on the same node; security groups and anything else IP-based won't help in this scenario.